# Extract phone numbers from comments

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

- I have column with comments in it (more then 5000 cases).
- Those comments have text, numbers, date, everything.
- I need to get phone number out of those comments.
- Phone numbers are in random places for every comment, so `LEFT`,`MID` or `RIGHT` will not work

The closest result that I have reached is with Kutools `=EXTRAXTNUMBERS()` ...... but I get a line of numbers which includes date, ID`s, etc.

Would prefer a formula. :)

Two sample comments below, required phone numbers are in **bold**

> Thursday, February 2, 2017 2:37 PM Coordinated Universal Time .3868 **67076939** ,pers .pārv.Tatjana Call outcome chosen: Noruna citā laikā - 2017-02-03 07:15 Wednesday, February 8, 2017 8:18 AM Coordinated Universal Time .3868 nr.**67074071**-neeksistē,personāla daļas vad.Tatjana neatbild,arī nr.**67076600** Call outcome chosen: Neceļ Friday, February 10, 2017 7:15 AM Coordinated Universal Time * .3868 *** piezv ap 13 Call outcome chosen: Noruna citā laikā - 2017-02-10 11:15
>
> Thursday, February 2, 2017 11:15 AM Coordinated Universal Time 4213 zvanīt **66119908** Call outcome chosen: Noruna citā laikā - 2017-02-07 09:00 Tuesday, February 14, 2017 12:59 PM Coordinated Universal Time .4532 * anita@dzintarniece@rtp.lv Call outcome chosen: Turpināt internetā

Comment: Genuine Excel Comments or just cells with mixed text in them ??

Comment: Cells with mixed text in them.

Comment: The numbers are always the first sequence of 8 digits in the comments? Maybe you can use this as an extracting rule.. It looks like they always came after the word "Time" and before the word "Call" too..

Comment: Try to specify what is specific about your phone numbers. For example, fixed number of digits? Do they always start with the same first few digits? The more you specify them the best results you will get from any suggested solution.

Comment: In comments there are 8 digit phone numbers, some starts with "2", some starts with "6".

Comment: @dot.Py Yes, phone numbers are between "Time" and "Call". There is just that in some cells there are one pair of these words, some have 3 or even more.

Comment: Do you need to do this with a formula, or can you use VBA ? The pattern is simply `\d{8}` ie. an 8 digit number. Your first example actually has 3 - what about `67074071` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Sorry, didnt noticed the third one. I`m not familiar with Visual Basic, so it would be great if i could do this with formula.

Answer (score 4):

This small *UDF()* will return all the 8 digit numeric sub-strings in a string:

```
Public Function PHNum(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    PHNum = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            temp = temp & CH
            If Len(temp) = 8 Then
                PHNum = PHNum & vbCrLf & temp
            End If
        Else
            temp = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

**Note:**

To get the stacked format in the output cell, format it to wrap on.

Comment: This was what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Regexp Solution**

This UDF extracts to you the phone numbers from a Text, as an array. You can eventually use `Join` to transform it into a csv string, or you can paste the array into a range of cells.

```
Function extractPhones(s As String) As String()
    Dim i As Long, matches, match, ret
    With CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\W[26]\d{7}\W"
        Set matches = .Execute(s)
    End With
    ReDim ret(1 To matches.Count) As String
    For Each match In matches
        i = i + 1
        ret(i) = Mid(match, 2, Len(match) - 2)
    Next
    extractPhones = ret
End Function
```

It uses a regular expression that matches phone number with these specs:

- are exactly 8 digits
- start by 6 or 2
- are not preceded or followed by an alphanumeric letter, but by blanks or punctuation characters.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Using an UDF you can accomplish this by using the following code:

To use it:

1. Press `ALT + F11`
2. Insert Module
3. Paste Code
4. In Excel Sheet, use this formula `=get_phone("CELL_WITH_NUMBER_HERE")` to get the first sequence of 8 digits in your cell.

**Code:**

```
Public Function get_phone(cell As Range)
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim num
    Dim counter As Integer

    'get cell value
    s = cell.Value

    'set the counter
    counter = 0
    'loop through the entire string
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        'check to see if the character is a numeric one
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) = True Then
            'add it to the number
            num = num + Mid(s, i, 1)
            counter = counter + 1
            'check if we've reached 8 digits
            If counter = 8 Then
                get_phone = num
                Exit Function
            End If
         Else
         'was not numeric so reset counter and answer
         counter = 0
         num = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

**Example Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) option that returns all matches to a single cell

[image]

See https://regex101.com/r/Hdv65h/1

```
Function StrPhone(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegexp As Object
    Set objRegexp = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    With objRegexp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = ".*?(\d{8})|.*$"
        StrPhone = Trim(.Replace(strIn, "$1 "))
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

There is add-on in Excel that I used in the past for regular expressions (http://seotoolsforexcel.com/regexpfind/). In your case, it could be complicated as you don't know how many times a phone number will appear in your cell. For these cases I suggest you use the VBA scripts that have been provided by other users.